# "404 Not found" error for my web page in LAN with lampp server on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, networking, xampp, lampp

I have setup a small website to access in our college LAN via LAMPP server installed on UBUNTU 14.04 LTS. Its a simple application containing few html and php pages, with database as mysql at back-end.

When we try to access this website in LAN, sometimes we get access to website correctly, where as sometimes we get "404 NOT FOUND" error.
Its completely unpredictable when we will get access and when we wont.

Is it a network issue? or what? We are clueless.

Can somebody help....

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Check if all required permissions are in place.

Comment: Yes all the permissions are in place, because I can access it sometimes and sometimes I cant. 
Also sometimes it happens that, if 2 PC's in the same lab are trying to access it, one of them is able to access, where as the other cant.

Comment: Does this happen with all the PCs in your lab? If this is specific to one or two PCs, then it might be something to do with the connections. If the issue is seen with all the PCs on a random basis, check end-to-end connections, and configurations as well.

Comment: It happens randomly... will check the configurations of pc's and connections again.... but that doesn't seem to be an issue... But still would chk it...

Comment: What is the exact error message in the Apache error log?

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem a week ago is there any files in the C:\wamp64\www directory, not sure what it is in Linux... Find the below text area in the httpd.conf file, found in C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf for Windows, and add your index page where i put my publish.htm page

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex publish.htm index.php
</IfModule>
```